# Binary search in a NSMutableArray of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, binary-search

Howdy all! First question here, so please be gentle :). I'm somewhat familiar with Objective-C but am having some problems with the particulars. In short, I want to know how I can performa a binary search on a NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries, and in that search, look for partial string syntax. I have an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries, where the array is a contact list and each NSDictionary is one contact (with four pieces of information). I managed to sort the array using

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:type  ascending:YES];
[addressBook sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

where the key is the user-supplied key in the dictionary. Part of the functionality of the program is to perform prefix searches on each piece of data in the individual contacts.

So while I have found -indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator: (and in particular, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995949/how-to-write-objective-c-blocks-inline), I can't figure out how to instruct the search to both search for the prefix of a string and how to implement the block syntax for the search itself.

I tried this - but I just get the ever so helpful "Expected expression" error, as I'm assuming I cannot substitute indexOfObjectPassingTest for indexOfObject.

```
unsigned index2 = [addressBook 
            indexOfObjectPassingTest:<#^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)predicate#>:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
                       inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [addressBook count]) 
                             options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual 
                     usingComparator:(NSComparator^(id obj1, id obj2)];
```

I'd appreciate any assistance in getting -indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator: to work, or if someone has another suggestion for binary search on an NSArray of NSDictionaries, I'm all ears.

(And yes, while this is for an algorithms assignment, it's programming language agnostic. I am trying to maximize speed, so my thought had been to the array each time you are searching on it. I had also thought of making copies of the array sorted for each dictionary key, but because we are dealing with large CSV files, that seemed a bit excessive. So any other Mac-specific asymptotic hints would be MUCH appreciated, as it's often hard to find that in Apple's documentation.)

Comment: Why do you use Objective C for that? It would be absolutely ineffective and some kind od reinventing the wheel. Just use NSDictionary of NSDictionaries. Or use old good C for that if you need performance, cause ObjC is principally slower.

Comment: Mostly because I'm trying to learn Objective C :). It's not about performance versus other types of code, just performance within our own implementations. Mostly I'm sure our prof wants binary search of some kind. So if your suggestion is to use NSDictionary of NSDictionary, you couldn't sort that because NSDictionary is by definition unsorted, right? So would you just iterate through the container NSDictionary linearly?

Comment: Well, you can use sorted array of keys to access dictionary in a particular order. Though i think this is not the best way to learn ObjC (implementing basic algorithms) :) It's too high level for that. Use C =)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Foundation framework does not let you explicitly specify binary search on NSArray unless you already have the object and looking for the index value (well obviously arrays are not always sorted).

One thing you could do is to get an array of values for the specified key, convert it to an CFArray (for free) and use Core Foundation's CFArrayBSearchValue function.

The other thing I would do is to add a category to NSArray which takes a block-formed comparator and implements binary search algorithm.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing the category approach (and learned about them in the process!) So the suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it. What can `CFArrayBSearchValues()` do that NSArray's `-indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` can't?

Comment: In any case, `CFArrayRef` and `NSArray*` are toll-free bridged. You can just cast one to the other type and it works exactly the same, so you can still use either `CFArrayBSearchValues()` or `-indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:`.